# @font-face working in one file, not in another

Tags: css, font-face

I've got a custom font setup on my site using @font-face in my stylesheet. It works just fine on my main page, but if I try to read the same stylesheet through another html file in a different directory, all of the styling will work fine except for the font.

The stylesheet (style.css) and font are in a /style/ directory.
The html file is in a sub-directory, and I'm reading the stylesheet using this:

```
<link href = "../style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
```

Again, it'll use all of the styling *except* the custom font. Why's that?

Comment: Where is the `@font-face` referencing?

Comment: It's referencing my /type/ directory. "src: url('type/ostrich-light-webfont.eot');"

Comment: As one answer said, it's best to use absolute URLs, such as `http://www.example.com/css/type/ostrich-light-webfont.eot`

Answer (score 1):

You should always use either absolute URLs (with the full domain name and everything), or URLs relative to the domain root (`/path/to/font.ttf`) to prevent confusion as to whether the font is being loaded relative to the stylesheet or the document.